# Android: change icon color in menu item

Tags: android

I have read as many similar posts as I have found on this topic and none of the proposed solutions seems to work.

I have a menu item with icon = ic_btn_speak_now

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/speech"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        android:title="Speak name"
        android:onClick="speechRecognition"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_checklist"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:onClick="searchChecklist"
        android:title="@string/search_checklist"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

It shows in the following layout AppBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChecklistActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/locationInfoContraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabAppBarLayout" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The icon shows up too dark. I want to change it to white. Here is how it currently looks...

[image]

How can I change this to white? Or something much brighter than this? Users cannot even see that the speaker item is even there. I have tried setting the tint to white and that works in Studio, but no changes in my AVD or actual device.

Comment: You are currently using an image asset from android which may not be a vector to support setting a colour. I would suggest you add an asset from the resource manager in Android Studio where you can select some of the icons provided for free. `File > New > Vector Asset` select `Clip Art` and choose the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "app:itemIconTint" property.

Comment: I added 'app:itemIconTint="@color/white"' in my XML '<item' and it had no effect. Am I missing something?